# In What year was "Al Pi Kabalah" first quoted for a Halachic ruling?

Tags: halacha, history, zohar

The phrase "al pi Kabalah" (based on Kabalah) is often used in teshuvot for various minhagim or halachot.

When is the first recorded instance of somebody recording the Halacha either "al pi Kabalah" or by quoting the Zohar?
 To clarify,  I want to know the Year. It does not matter if they were a major posek or not, just as long a they were mentioning practical rather than theoretical halacha.
If they are quoting the zohar they have to mention it by name.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3826

Comment: I voted to close because the other question asks for all books of the class of which this question asks for the earliest member. cc @WAF

Comment: That doesn't even come close to answering myvquestion!!!!!

Comment: @msh210 This question is not asking about books!!!

Comment: @avi, sorry, I said books, but I didn't really mean it. The other question asks about "authors or codifiers of _halacha_", like this one.

Comment: @avi you want quotes not brought in books? Where would you find such a quote?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin he said. _T'shuvos_. Not all of them have been compiled into books -- not by a long shot.

Comment: Regardless,  the year is what I care about, and is what the question asks for. That other answer isn't exhaustive by any means! I also don't care if they were a major posek or not.

Comment: @msh210 That question is limited to "major authors or codifiers of halacha" whereas this one isn't. I support reopening.

Comment: @DoubleAA, and you have support from one reopen-voter. Go ahead. avi, I suggest you further [edit] this to clarify the difference between it and the other question.

Comment: Avi, are you looking for a source quoting the Zohar specifically, or any legal ruling based on 'the hidden Torah'? If the latter, than the answer would be someone very early (all of the Chasidei Ashkenaz, for example)

Comment: Would _Beit Yosef_ 's statement on [Tur Orach Chayim 426](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1934) "והר"י גיקטילי"א בעל שערי אורה כתב בתשובה ש**על פי הקבלה** אין לברך על חידוש הלבנה עד שיעברו עליה ז' ימים" qualify with regard to [R. Yosef Gikatilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Abraham_Gikatilla) (especially considering it is brought _le-Halakhah_ in [Shulchan Arukh Orach Chayim 426:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2141), even against the _Rif_, the _Rambam_ and the _Rosh_ who say one is obligated to do _Qidush Levanah_ from the first day)?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the Bet Yosef is one of the earliest to quote the Zohar as the source of a Halacha.

The first instance, IIRC, is the various *details* of *Negel Vaser*, like pouring from one vessel to another and not using the water for anything else.

He actually prefaces this section with an announcement [caveat?] that these Halachot are not found in writings of other Poskim:

> וכן כתכ בספר הזוהר פרשת *וישב* על פסוק *ויאמר האיש נסעו מזה*
>    ועוד כתובים שם בנטילת ידים שחרית **חדושין שאינם נמצאים בפוסקים** וז״ל ...‏

Source: [Tur Orach Chaim Ch. 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43059&st=&pgnum=11) - 4th wide line.

The Bet Yosef [on the Tur] was completed in **1547**, according to Wikipedia in [Hebrew](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3).

Comment: (1) Where does the Bet Yosef mention the obligation to wash _Negel Vaser_ before doing anything else being from the Zohar? [Ba'er Heitev on Orach Chayim 1:1 s.v. ha-Shachar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=6) comments on the Bach's surprise at the _Beit Yosef_ for **not** having mentioned the _Zohar_ 's position on the importance of _Netilat Yadayim_ before all else. (2) Hebrew Wikipedia's article on the [Beit Yosef](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/בית_יוסף) says it's writing (which took 25 years) was completed in 1547.

Comment: @TamirEvan - I wrote that from [faulty] memory (which is why I said IIRC.) I'm going to edit it.

Comment: I do have another question: Considering the _Beit Yosef_ is actually a commentary on the _Arba'ah Turim_, bringing various Halakhic sources to bare on the latter, with the _Shulchan Arukh_ bringing the author's actual _Pesaq_ (and especially considering it's introduction claiming to decide _Halakhah_ based on the majority of the _Rif_, the _Rambam_ and the _Rosh_, unless existing custom or majority of other _Poseqim_ is otherwise), does the _Beit Yosef_ qualify as R. Karo making a Halachic ruling based on Kabalah (or as "recording the Halacha either 'al pi Kabalah' or by quoting the Zohar")?

Comment: @TamirEvan - that's a fascinating question - which should be sent to the community for its own consideration.

Comment: I believe the Beis Yosef's uncle was very into paskening from kabbala, perhaps even more than the Beis Yosef. His responsa are cited by the Beis Yosef IIRC.