Saying something in the name of someone who never actually said it
I remember years ago reading in one of Aryeh Kaplan's compendium works, a law that when someone feels confident that they're saying something correctly, that they can actually say it in the name of a big rabbi who never actually said it. Could somebody please confirm this? Thank you.

Rav Moshe Feinstein said he had never heard anything like that in his entire life ;)

Welcome to MiYodeya Gary and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Shemot 23:7 מִדְּבַר־שֶׁ֖קֶר תִּרְחָ֑ק - distance yourself from false matters...

https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.28a.19?lang=bi&with=all

היתלה באילן גדול pesachim 112

I heard in the name of @יהושעק that it's permissible to josh in the comments of Mi Yodeya. It's called "joshing" because of יהושעק

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132636/31534, and the concept of pseudepigrapha

As the Chasam Sofer once said "I don't care if you say my Torah in your name. But don't ever say your Torah in my name"

The מגן אברהם brings based on 2 gemaras
אם שמע דין ונראה לו שהלכה כך מותר לאמרו בשם אדם גדול כי היכי דליקבלי מיניה [עירובין דף נ"א ופסחים דף קי"ב]
"If one hears a halacha that appears correct to himself, he may say it over in the name of a gadol in order that others will accept it"
As many in the comments pointed out, I should add that the מגן אברהם does go on to brings sources that seem to contradict this, and leaves the issue unresolved.

I would note that אדם גדול has a different connotation גדול הדור, and when we just say "gadol" we usually mean the latter

You don't have to go very far, the Magain Avraham brings a contradictory source right after that and leaves it by a צריך עיון.

It's unclear from Rashi's explanation of P'sachim 112a that Rabbi Akiva advised people to misattribute sayings. It's likely Rashi is explaining Rabbi Akiva to mean that if you correctly attribute a saying to a great person, people will take it more seriously than if you say it on your own authority. Additionally, the Gemara in Eruvin seems like a special circumstance where it was exigent for Rabba and Rav Yosef to establish their place of residence before nightfall, and Rabba, who knew the b'raisa was authoritative, could not risk Rav Yosef missing the deadline while he pondered the matter.
