# Sources for Halachic opinions influenced by kabbalah

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, mysticism-kabbalah, practical-kabbalah

Is there a source (like a book, website, etc.) that has a list of halachic opinions/rulings based on kabbalah and/or the Zohar? I’m asking because I am looking more into Halachic methodology and I know many rabbis take Kabbalah into consideration.

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/kabala-in-halacha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Olamot.net](https://olamot.net) has a [halachic write-up](https://olamot.net/shiurim/%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94/) of the cross-section of Kabbalah and Halachah, discussing the various opinions on how to rule in case of conflict between Gemara and Kabballistic sources, on various kabbalistic rulings that have entered normative halacha, and the weight of Kabbalistic practices not mentioned in Talmud.

This is a link to their [source sheet](https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=1AVcBs9b_9tYKBO2qK1sUSyhp2zckmU4l&export=download).

Comment: Which kabbalistic practices are mentioned in the Talmud?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think he meant "the weight of practices brought down in Kabbala which aren't mentioned in Talmud"

Comment: @Loani what other kind of kabbalistic practice is there

Answer (score 2):

Rav Asher Weiss has a long discussion about when to Pasken Halacha according to Kabbala [here](https://minchasasher.com/he/shiur/parsha-vort/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%96%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94/), which includes many examples from the Shulchan Aruch and elsewhere, especially from section 5 (בענייני תפילין ותפילה) and on.

He also brings different Rishonim's and Achronim's opinions on how to treat Kabbala in relation to Halacha, which might help your understanding of when Kabbala is taken into consideration (even in cases that aren't given as examples in the above link)